# What is /etc/ca-certificates/extracted for?

Tags: networking, security, ssl, pacman, certificates

I am running Arch Linux.  I did the first update today in an embarrassingly long time.  I had a conflict, that there was a file `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` that was a soft link to a file `/etc/ca-certificates/extracted/tls-ca-bundle.pem` that no package seemd to own, which prevented the install of `ca-certificates-utils` package.  I removed the file and continued with the installation.

But I don't think I've ever monkied with anything in `/etc/ssl/certs` or `/etc/ca-certificates`.  **What does the name "extracted" mean for the folder `/etc/ca-certificates/extracted`?  How would something get there?**

I'm trying to decide if the conflict is related to Arch packaging changes, my own bad memory, or some sort of foul play.

Answer (score 0):

according to [man update-ca-trust](https://man.archlinux.org/man/update-ca-trust.8), the files in extracted folder is dynamically generated, so they won't belong to any package.